# VS2010 express on 64Bit windows - can it compile 32bit binaries without the win7 sdk?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit

i can't find this information anywhere. I know that if you install vs2010 express on a 32bit os you need the win7 sdk to build 64 bit, but is it the same the other way round?

EDIT - I am interested in the c++ version, but I guess it's probably the same for others

thanks

oli

Answer (score 3):

By default VS2010 Express will **only** target Win32. It doesn't matter if you are running Win7-64, MSVC++ Express uses the 32-bit tools unless you install the SDK.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx):

> 64-bit tools are not available on Visual C++ Express by default. To enable 64-bit tools on Visual C++ Express, install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) in addition to Visual C++ Express.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to successfully build and deploy C# apps from a Win 7 64bit machine onto machines running 32 bit Windows XP, Vista and Win 7 without any extra SDK. So far I have had no issues.

Regards

AJ

Comment: Did it install the 64-bit compiler too (i.e. can you target it in your projects) or just the 32-bit?

Comment: Yes I am able to target both 32bit and 64bit in my projects. Note that I am using C# though, not C++.

Comment: Thanks - no, I think that's more which versions of the .NET frameworks are installed. Sounds like the VC++ express install includes the 32-bit compiler only regardless of your OS's 32/64 bits